# JavaFX PropertyValueFactory unable to receive property from a class located in different packages

Tags: java, javafx, package

I have two packages, one for objects and the other for creating GUI. I am trying to create a `TableView` in JavaFX and I have to use `PropertyValuesFactory<>(property)` to get the value of the object. So I have a bug where if I put the Person and GUI class in the same package everything would work for fine, but when the Person class is put in the objects package everything goes bad and I get this error:

```
WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'name' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@6771b7fb with provided class type: class uni.rest.objects.Person
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module javafx.base cannot access class uni.rest.objects.Person (in module main) because module main does not open uni.rest.objects to javafx.base
```

This is also the line of code where the error happens:

```
person_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
```

So I assume that the property value location might have to be changed...
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the Java 9+ module system, but it looks like you have not configured your modules correctly, based on the error you're receiving. `uni.rest.objects` is not accessible to the JavaFX modules.

Comment: The execption just tells you what you need to add to the `main` module: `opens uni.rest.objects to javafx.base;`. (This allows reflective access to all types in the package.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `PropertyValueFactory` class uses reflection to access the model class' properties. The module system added in Java 9 adds greater encapsulation which prevents modules from reflectively accessing other modules unless given permission by directives in `module-info.java`.

The [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) of `PropertyValueFactory` mentions what you need to do if deploying your application as a module:

> **Deploying an Application as a Module**
>
> If the referenced class is in a named module, then it must be reflectively accessible to the `javafx.base` module. A class is reflectively accessible if the module [opens](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html?is-external=true#isOpen(java.lang.String,java.lang.Module)) the containing package to at least the `javafx.base` module. Otherwise the [`call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html#call(javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures)) method will log a warning and return `null`.
>
> For example, if the `Person` class is in the `com.foo` package in the `foo.app` module, the `module-info.java` might look like this:
>
> ```
> module foo.app {
>     opens com.foo to javafx.base;
> }
> ```
>
> Alternatively, a class is reflectively accessible if the module [exports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html?is-external=true#isExported(java.lang.String)) the containing package unconditionally

---

Another option is to forgo `PropertyValueFactory` and use a custom `Callback`. The `PropertyValueFactory` was more of a convenience for when lambdas were not a thing; before lambdas, if one wanted to use a custom `Callback`, one would have to create an anonymous class each time which was verbose. Since lambdas, however, one can do:

```
person_column.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().nameProperty());
```

Obviously, this works best if the model exposes a JavaFX property. The advantages of a custom `Callback` include avoidance of reflection and type safety.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, I appreciate the explanation I am new to module system.

Comment: There are similar requirements for the [`Application` subclass' package](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) as well as [packages containing FXML-related objects](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#deploy_as_module).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was the capitalization in the getter function.
I was trying to access it with this

```
productIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("id"));
```

this worked:

```
public int getId(){
    return this.id;
}
```

But if I had GetId or getid it would give me the error.

This has to do with how the PropertyValueFactory  finds the value with the getter function. You can read more about why this is at: https://visdup.blogspot.com/2019/04/javafx-propertyvaluefactory-is-not-able.html

Answer (score -1):

Yeah,  Controller and Class Person need to be in one package

Comment: no, that's plain wrong ..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).